# How to get Firebase Value and display image on Android apps

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The Android app and Firebase are connected.

When a flame is detected by the Arduino flame detection sensor, the data value(name : "state") in the Firebase changes from 1 to 0 as follows:

[image]

I want to automatically display the image in the Android app when this value("state") changes to 0.

this is my code

```
package com.example.framelayoutex;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
  private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  private void readState(String state){
      TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              /*You're only going to get the last value of 'state'*/
              mDatabase.child("state").limitToLast(1).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                      ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.fire);
                      if (task.isSuccessful())/*Communication with Firebase succeeded*/ {
                          Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
                          int firescan = (int) task.getResult().getValue();
                          if (firescan == 0){
                              imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          }
                          else{
                              imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                          }
                      }
                      else {
                          Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());/*Communication with Firebase failed*/
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
      }; 
  }
}
```

I took the last value of the state of the firebase and put it in an int-type variable called firescan,
if firescan is 0, the image is visible, and if it's 1, the image is invisible.

It runs without errors, but the image does not change as desired.

I want to know why, but I'm a beginner, so I don't know what's wrong. I should like to have the benefit of your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

The code in your `onComplete` will need to handle the fact that it gets a list, by looping over `task.getResult().getChildren()`:

```
mDatabase.child("state").limitToLast(1).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.fire);
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            for (DataSnapshot result: snapshot.getChildren()) { // 
                int firescan = result.getValue(Integer.class);
                if (firescan == 0){
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir. but I still can't print out the image

Comment: That's a bit vague given the explanation I've given on why your original code doesn't work, and the changes in my answer. Did you run the modified code in a debugger already and step through the `onComplete`? What happened at each line when you did that? Did it go into the new loop? What was the value for `firescan`? Did that make sense to you?

Comment: It took me a while to understand T.T
I tried debugging, but I don't think the readstate method can be executed at all.
I temporarily tried to print the system out in oncrate, but nothing appears in logcat. I'll try many things again.